# Tasks mismatch inputs

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I'm having a little issue. I have a BackgroundWorker that reads a text file line for line. I want to perform actions on those read in lines, but this action takes quiet a while, so i thought i could create tasks that run parallel for this sort of work. This is my code so far:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(this.AppData_Path + this.Playlists_File))
{
    string line = "";

    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
        {
            Task temp = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AddSearchPlaylistToList(line));

            tasks.Add(temp);
        }

        if (tasks.Count >= MaxThreads) // MaxThreads = 20
        {
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

            tasks = new List<Task>();
        }
    }
}
```

Now this is where my problem starts, for some odd reason multiple tasks work on the same line. I printed out the lines in the BackgroundWorker, before it's submited to a Task and it looked like this:

```
line1 345893798537598375 
line2 435803948508394534 
line3 475734573478534879 
line4 438348975347895798 
line5 234234234234234242
...
```

when i printed the line parameter in the AddSearchPlaylistToList void the tasks are working on, for some reason, it looked like this:

```
line1 345893798537598375 
line1 345893798537598375 
line2 435803948508394534 
line2 435803948508394534
line2 435803948508394534
line3 475734573478534879
...
```

so the inputs seem to be messed up, but I can't explain why.

Comment: This looks like a situation where `Parallel.ForEach` should be used

Comment: If you use tasks you don't need a BGW at all. It's nothing more than the equivalent to a `Task.Run` without the ability to `await`. You don't need lists of tasks either, or manually set the number of threads - that's what *Tasks* and Task schedulers are for.

Comment: What does `AddSearchPlaylistToList` do? You may not need tasks at all, or you can modify it so it runs better with tasks. If, for example, it appends anything to a list, you could use LINQ on the file and get the resulting list directly from the lines. Or you could replace the list with a ConcurrentQueue that can be modified by multiple threads without locking

Comment: I would go with the `Parallel.ForEach` option provided by @PanagiotisKanavos. No need to reinvent the wheel. I speak from experience ;) did once the same stuff, when I did no know that such `Parallel` stuff already exists

Answer (score 2):

Try this: simply save the line in an extra local variable and pass this variable into the task:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
{
    string tempLine = line;
    Task temp = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AddSearchPlaylistToList(tempLine ));

    tasks.Add(temp);
}
```

This phenomenon is called closures. One of the best [articles](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) about it is from Jon Skeet.

The lambda `() => AddSearchPlaylistToList(temp)` captures the value of the variable line and extends it over the life time of the variable.

Basically it means, that when the Task really starts (which is hard to tell when exactly it happens) it will return to this line:

```
Task temp = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AddSearchPlaylistToList(line));
```

and only at this point it will take the value from the variable `line`. But by now your loop has advanced and this value might be now different from the time when that task was created. Several tasks that start at the same time, will grab the same value from `line`. The worst thing that could happen is that when the task starts `line` could actually be empty and the if-clause which is supposed to prevent this becomes useless.

The temporary saving ensures that each value of `line` will be captured independently.

Comment: A better option would be to pass the value as a state parameter to StartNew. Even better though is to use the appropriate TPL classes and avoid the manual iteration, the list of tasks and `Task.StartNew`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos good advice, personally I would use the `Parallel.For` option.

Answer (score 2):

[File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) already returns an enumerator over the lines of a file so you don't need to use StreamReader directly. You don't need the list of tasks to collect all tasks, either. You could write :

```
var tasks= File.ReadLines(somePath)
                .Select(line=>Task.Run(AddSearchPlaylistToList(line)));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

If you have to limit the number of concurrent tasks (why? it matters), you could use a custom TaskScheduler. An easier option would be to use [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783747(v=vs.110).aspx) with a MaxDOP limit, eg:

```
var lines=File.ReadLines(somePath);
var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreesOfParallelism = 20};
Parallel.ForEach(lines,options,line=>AddSearchPlaylistToList(line));
```

Comment: may be you should exclude the empty lines like OP tried with the if-condition